# Why float value is giving me 0 value even though i have used float datatype and specifier correctly

Tags: c, factorial

I am writing a code for factorial and summation and then adding them together. My output is not giving correct answer. The negative answer is not being shown when i run the code.

Code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float f1(int num1);
int f2(int num2);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    float y = f1(n)+f2(n);

    printf("Value of y is: %3f",y);

    return 0;
}

float f1(int num1)
{
    int fact = 1;
    int n1 = num1+1;

    for(int i=1 ;i<=n1; i++)
    {
        fact = fact*i;
    }
    printf("factorial = %d \n", fact );

    int f0 = pow(-1,num1);
    printf("pow = %d \n", f0 );

    float f1 = f0/fact ;
    printf("f1 = %f \n", f1 );

    return f1;

}

int f2(int num2)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int j=0;j<=4;j++)
    {
        sum = sum + 2*num2;
    }
    printf("f2 = %d \n", sum );
    return sum;
}
```

My output picture is this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZsVn.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you refer to is in this line:

```
float f1 = f0 / fact;
```

As both `f0` and `fact` are `int` the result is `int` even if you assign it to `float`.

You can solve this by casting one of the operands:

```
float f1 = (float)f0 / fact;
```

[ISO/IEC 9899:2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) §6.5.5 6 states:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.<sup>105)</sup> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a` [...]
>
> <sup>105)</sup> This is often called "truncation toward zero".

Comment: Thankyou so much. i was missing this error. Such a small mistake i did

Comment: @HaniaSalman, glad to help, it happened to me too, some years ago :)

Comment: @anastaciu Did you already noticed the new "thank you" hand claps? Isn't that unuseful?  Your answer could have 2 upvotes already (or maybe even three).

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio, yes I did notice it, I don't know what's it about, you're right, it may suppress upvotes, let's wait for news.

Comment: @anastaciu https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398422/12139179